# Pop-up modal on clicking 'Add to Cart' button!

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento2.2

In Magento-2.2, when we click 'Add to Cart' button,
we need to show the following message as a pop-up modal:

> "Product is added to cart!"

I know how to create modal outside of Magento with css.

But I failed to implement that inside Magento
by changing in this file:

`app/design/frontend/MyVendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

> REMOVEED CODE:

```
<button type="submit"
        title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
        class="action primary tocart"
        id="product-addtocart-button">
    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
</button>
```

> ADDED CODE:

```
<a href="#url">

<button type="submit"
        title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
        class="action primary tocart"
        id="product-addtocart-button">
    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
</button>

</a>
<div id="url" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#x" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <p>Product is added to cart!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have you done this already?
Please show us your experience.
Is there any other way?
Big Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing same issue . Could anyone please help us?

Comment: https://www.tigren.com/product/magento-2-ajax-add-to-cart/ try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom script

```
    <a href="#url">
<button type="submit"
        title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
        class="action primary tocart"
        id="product-addtocart-button">
    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
</button>
    </a>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <span class="close">&times;</span>
           <p>
             Your Custom Message
           </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Apply CSS to hide the custom message and modal

```
    .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Apply Script

```
requirejs([
    'jquery'
], function($) {
    $(".action").click(function(e) {
        $(".modal").css("display","block");
    });

    $(".close").click(function(e) {
        $(".modal").css("display","none");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it.
The main role behind this add to cart functionallity is played by -
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

Option 1 -

Override vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js in your module and in the ajaxSubmit() function trigger your popup modal in the ajax success section.

Option 2 -

The ajax submit function triggers a custom event 'ajax:addToCart' in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js file. You can simply create layout catalog_product_view.xml and add your js.
Inside the JS you can add event listener to this event and then trigger your modal -

example -

```
require([
"jquery",
"mage/url"
], 
function ($,url) {
    $(document).on("ajax:addToCart",function(){
        //openModal
    })         
});
```